# PostgreSQL suitabilty of Hash Index on PK and FK

Tags: postgresql, index

I read [this not so recent article](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/hash-indexes-are-faster-btree-indexes) about Hash Index performance on PostgreSQL, where the author writes:

> ...the hash index performs better than the btree index and the performance difference is in the range of 10% to 22%. In some other workloads we have seen a better performance like with hash index on varchar columns and even in the community, it has been reported that there is performance improvement in the range of 40% to 60% when hash indexes are used for unique index columns.

Assuming that your PostgreSQL is at leat version 10 (to have the index WAL-logged) and (as usually happens) you only have equality comparisons on PK and FK columns, my question is:

*Shouldn’t be Hash index preferred to B-Tree index on PK and FK column, due to the (slightly) better performance and for the smaller memory footprint?*

While I’m writing, I’m asking if the `IN` operator can use that kind of index, since it might be the only one other operator (other than `=`) usually involved in lookup queries on those kind of columns, and if not, this may respond to my answer (negetively).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash indexes do not currently support unique indexes, and so not PK or FK either.  Maybe in a future version...

Comment: Yes, I found the same response also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274080/postgres-hash-index-with-unique-constraint.